Function unwind data neither in __unwind_info nor in __eh_frame
iOS binary, release build, ARM64. I am looking at a function that does some floating point work.
The binary has both an __unwind_info section and an __eh_frame section. The IP (PC) for the function can be found in the former - but with the NOP encoding (0), meaning the unwind info is not available. It is not listed in __eh_frame at all.
Looking at the function prologue, it doesn't fit into the compact unwind format for ARM64 (some register saves are for floating point), but it surely fits into the DWARF unwind format. The prologue goes:
stp d15, d14, [sp,#-160]!
stp d13, d12, [sp,#16]
stp d11, d10, [sp,#32]
stp d9, d8, [sp,#48]
stp x28, x27, [sp,#64]
stp x26, x25, [sp,#80]
stp x24, x23, [sp,#96]
stp x22, x21, [sp,#112]
stp x20, x19, [sp,#128]
stp x29, x30, [sp,#144]
add x29, sp, #0x90
sub sp, sp, #0x190

How is one supposed to unwind it?
